# jQuery not showing å characters correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a word like åsdf. When I receive the word by jquery I get &#229sdf. It replaces å by &#229.

How can I get exact word like  åsdf.

Anyone has solution!!

Thanks advance.

Comment: how you are getting that word. can you post some code?

Comment: what encoding are you using? utf-8?

Comment: Receive how, from where?

Comment: You must have encoding and conversion problems on several levels here. Without knowing where this value comes from and how it's being transcoded/encoded/escaped, we can't really say anything. One thing's for sure: this is not a *jQuery* problem.

Comment: <%IList<Track> tracks = ViewData["tracks"] as IList<Track>;%>.I take data from database. For example: alert(tracks.title):

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it seems you're using Asp.net MVC.

Make sure your site serves text as UTF-8. You can use @Html.Raw and it won't encode Unicode characters but could lead to XSS issues.

If you're using .net 4.5, I would suggest you to use [AntiXSSEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.aspx), which will handles unicode characters correctly and encodes bad elements () and go through below link:

[Disable encoding of unicode characters in ASP.NET-MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580876/disable-encoding-of-unicode-characters-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.html()` function of jquery to get that exact word including special characters like 'åsdf'.

For Example:

```
var i = $("#ac").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with the browser not understanding the encoding of your page, try

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```